# Rendering same view and preventing Form resubmission confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-views

I have a simple index page with the form to get some feedback from people and after submitting this form my view just loads the same page. This occurs "Form resubmission" confirmation in Chrome Browser (probably in other browsers too). I don't want to create the second page with confirmation I do confirmation just with small alert on the top of my page after form submitting.

So could I solve this problem? Most of the answers I saw until says that there must be redirect function, but redirect takes not a context in my case I need the context to know that the form was submitted and show the alert to inform the users. My view:

```
def index(request):
    if request.POST:
        showAlert = True
        # Collect form data
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        to_email = 'example@email.com'
        message = 'message: {}\nname: {}\nemail: {}'.format(
                request.POST.get('message'),
                name,
                request.POST.get('email')
            )
        subject = 'feedback'
        try:
            email = EmailMessage(
                subject,
                message,
                django_settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                [to_email]
            )
            email.send(fail_silently=False)
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return render(request, 'project/index.html', {'showAlert': showAlert})
    else:
        return render(request, 'project/index.html')
```

And here is the form:

```
<form id="frm_feedback" role="form" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message" name="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So if someone submits the form it will send post and my view index method will collect all data from this form and send me an email and then render the same page with additional context as '{'showAlert': showAlert}' and I can show alert using JavaScript.

After that, if I try to reload “Confirm form resubmission” browser alert occurs and I can't reload the page anymore.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question. Are you saying you want to be able to reload the page without the confirm form resubmission box showing up? I'm afraid that's built into browsers, and is an important feature, otherwise users could inadvertently send you multiple emails by refereshing the page many times. So I'm not sure why you would want to disable it. (Users generally will not refresh a page after a form submission, so you shouldn't design your site around this anyway.)

Comment: Yeah this is what I will. Reload same page and show alert that form was sent.

Comment: Oh I just reread your question - so you want to do a redirect (which avoids the popup coming if you refresh the page), but still have a message telling the user their form was successfully submitted? In that case Django's built-in [messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/) framework sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: I see, didn't knew about messages, I'll check it, thank you!